# How to make a Command Line application with WebRTC in Linux?

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, webrtc

I have an idea for a side project where i will connect two terminals(clients) using WebRTC and they will share some data with each other(assume a CLI chat app) using Node.js. But wherever i read about WebRTC it always says that it works only in browsers. Like the fact that if a machine does not have a browser that supports WebRTC then it would not work in the machine. Do statements like these mean that WebRTC can only work in the browser. If not then how should i approach making something like this?

The functions i want the application to have :-

1.) It should connect with the peer when i write "node client.js" in the terminal (client.js will be the client script).

2.) The terminals should be able to send each other messages.

3.) No need of the browser.

I've made such applications using WebSockets and i dont intend to use them in this project.

Comment: Yes, you can use WebRTC without browser, and from CLI, too. But WebRTC relies on external signalling, so you will need WebSockets or some other mechanism to establish a session.

Comment: can i use the getUserMedia API in terminal? I intend to take snapshots from the webcam and convert it to ascii and show it in the terminal.

Comment: You should be able to get frames from the webcam on Linux (if you have the correct access permissions), but I don't think WebRTC can help you with image conversion to ascii.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea this is possible, and people are doing it today!

Check out [ascii](https://github.com/dialup-inc/ascii) it is a command line WebRTC client that does camera capture and encoding. It uses the Golang library [pion/webrtc](https://github.com/pion/webrtc)

I am sure it is possible with nodejs as well, but don't know how much work it would be.

---

Also if you are doing chat only it is even easier! See [pion-to-pion](https://github.com/pion/webrtc/tree/master/examples/pion-to-pion) really easy example to have two processes communicate via WebRTC.